# Django, how to create unique number with specific number

Tags: python, django

I would like to create unique 5 digit number (id_number) for profile given that the first two is the year that students start study. For example, students enrolled in 2019 have to have id starting with 19 in the first two and random number for other three digits. Thank for all solutions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id_number` is unique (`unique=True` in the model field), you can simply do something like

```py
import random
from django.utils.timezone import now

# ...

year_part = now().year % 100
while True:
  id_number = '%02d%03d' % (year_part, random.randint(0, 999))
  if not Profile.objects.filter(id_number=id_number).exists():
    break
# assign the id_number to a profile...
```

Note that this *may* crash with an `IntegrityError` when you attempt to `.save()` the model in the unlucky (1/999) case two concurrent requests are generating the same id_number, in which case you can simply try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
number=int('{}{}'.format(int(str(year)[-2:]),random.randint(100, 999)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to use it, try the following

```
import random
import datetime
def generate_id(year=None, digits=5):
    if not year:
        year=datetime.datetime.now().year
    year = str(year)
    digits = int(digits)
    data = str(random.randint(0,999)) + year[-2:]
    return data.zfill(digits)[-digits:]
```

This make sure you have 5 digits

Answer (score 0):

```
import randint from random
def random_with_N_digits(n):  # generate OTP
    range_start = 10**(n - 1)
    range_end = (10**n) - 1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)
```